# What is wrong with my file name?

Tags: html, web

I copied this web page from [here](http://www.sqlsaturday.com/588/Sessions/Schedule.aspx) to a Windows machine then I renamed it from *SQLSaturday #588 - New York City 2017  Sessions  Schedule.htm* to *SQLSaturday #588 - New York City 2017  Sessions.html*.  I edited the page to remove some stuff like the download buttons and it loaded fine on my machine.

I then uploaded it to my GitHub account.  Now it is broke and I do not know why.  It 404s on this:

marvelous-software.github.io/SQLSaturday/SQLSaturday%20#588 - New York City 2017  Sessions.html

I do not know why it puts a %20 for one single space occurrence and not the rest.  Doesn't matter though since if I replace the %20 with a space or all the spaces with %20 it fails just the same.  If I rename the file to x.html it works.

Anyone know why I can not use the file name and what I can do to fix it?
This is [my page](https://marvelous-software.github.io/).  You need to click **Events** then **SQL Saturday** so there will be two links, SQL Saturday 588, NYC, May 20, 2017.  One works and the other is broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest problem is the # sign. When I encode it with %23, it works for me.

The really correct encoding is
SQLSaturday%20%23588%20-%20New%20York%20City%202017%20%20Sessions.html

but for Firefox, only the %23 seems to matter.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  I updated it to use the correct encoding.  any other characters I should be aware of that you know about?  This is my first web site.

Comment: I'd use some web encoder, if I were you. For example this one: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/. Put a part of the URL in the text area and select 'encode'. But always make it just an isolated part of the url, like the sections between the / signs.